# date and time checking with phones date and time

Tags: android, alarm, datepickerdialog

I am trying to create an app which checks the date and time given by the user with the date and time of the phone and does a specific task . I am able to take inputs using date and time picker dialog but i am facing problems how to process them.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int SystemsTimeHour;
int SystemsTimeMin;

int hour ;
int min;

Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TimePickerDialog tpd  = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    hour = hourOfDay;
                    min = minute;
                }
            }, hour, min, true);
                  tpd.show();

        }
    });

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            alarmIntent);
}
```

}

Comment: How to manipulate those data ...

Comment: I want it to work as an alarm clock like it checks the systems time again and again until it reaches the user given time and does the specific task.

Comment: you can use an `AlarmManager` to do that

Comment: do you know any video tutorials or links which can help ?

Comment: Asking tutorials is offtopic here, please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fire a PendingIntent at a specific time using AlarmManager.

For example if you want to wake up at 5.30, create a calendar instance using this time.

```
int hour = 5;
int minute = 30;

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR,hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Then create a PendingIntent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(your_context,AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(your_context, 0,intent, 0);
```

Then using AlarmManger object set to wake up PendingIntent at the specified time

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

You can implement your features in the broadcast receiver.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }
}
```

register your receiver in the manifest

```
<receiver
    android:name="yourpackagename.AlarmReceiver"
    android:process=":remote" >
</receiver>
```

Comment: Boss i tried it but didn't get any toast on my given time ... i posted my code as an answer. can you check it ??

Comment: Please check the edited manifest file. You have to use your own package name.

Comment: Boss i have used your code and it works fine but i am trying to take inputs from users so i am using a timepickerdialog .. but the alarm goes on when the app starts ... it doesn't wait for the input and even if input is given by timepickerdialog it sodesn't work ... but if i assign inputs like u did ... it works fine .. could u have a look at the code that i have given in my question ??

Comment: i am taking the values from onTimeSet methods ... i am taking those hourofDay and minute into integers hour and min ....
 public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    hour = hourOfDay;
                    min = minute;
                }

Answer (score 0):

Make a calendar object like so:

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance()
```

This object is based on the devices system settings, which is exactly what you want. Now, to get the time:

```
Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Or you can use this:

---

> public final Date getTime ()
>   Added in API level 1
>
> Returns the time of this Calendar as a Date object.
>   Throws
>   IllegalArgumentException   if the time is not set and the time cannot be >computed from the current field values.

From android docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29

Once you have the system time, to compare it with your time do this:

```
if(myTime == SystemsTime){
//Do this
}else{
//Do this
}
```

You can just set `SystemsTime` to `Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);` or `Calendar.getTime()`.

```
int SystemsTime = Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Comment: Ruchir it works but it doesn't work as i intended it to work . I want it to work as an alarm clock like it checks the systems time again and again until it reaches the user given time and does the specific task. Your given solution doesn't do that

Comment: @Saud in that case, you can use a while loop, that will constantly check. Or, you can have an endless for loop which only ends **when** the times are equal. That should work for sure. Let me know :-)

Comment: @Saud Send me your new code, and I'll try to find and solve the problem